# Jekyll not serving with drafts option

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll is not serving when I use the `--drafts` flag. I get the following error:

```
[2017-02-11 15:49:48] ERROR `/files/' not found
```

It works fine when I don't call `--drafts`.

So, this works:

```
jekyll serve --watch --baseurl ""
```

But this doesn't:

```
jekyll serve --watch --baseurl --drafts ""
```

I have also tried removing all else, so it is just:

```
jekyll serve --drafts
```

I have a draft post in my _drafts directory, which is marked with `draft: true` (I have also tried `published: false` and leaving that out entirely.

The contents of _config.yml are:

```
baseurl: /blog
exclude: ['README.md']
permalink: pretty

# Conversion
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge

# Markdown Processors
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  auto_ids: true
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

It might be worth noting that syntax highlighting isn't working either, so the errors may (or may not) be related.

Comment: @marcanuy: question edited to include _config.yml

Comment: /files/ is just the name of a page on the site. It's because I was trying to refresh on that page. If I do it on the root, then it's same result but with ERROR `/` not found

Comment: did you try localhost:4000/blog ?

Comment: Yeah. Everything works fine until I call the --drafts flag. All addresses are fine until then.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access for the draft? Since you have permalink: pretty, it should be something like localhost:4000/blog/2017/03/01/something/ depending on the name of the draft and the date you last edited it. Or did you try adding a list of all posts to see if it's included there?

Comment: Or serve it with option `--show-dir-listing`, which should make your index just show a directory listing and see if it's there.